# how i make this function fit for every variable

Tags: python

i got this function but it only fit variable a and i want it fit for every variable without change the function every time.

```
def count_input_a(numbers_of_letters):
    global a
    if numbers_of_letters == 0:
        a = 13
    else:
        a = int(a)
```

I want one function that fit for multipale variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly why using `global` to return a value is bad -- it ties the function to a particular variable in the caller's namespace, which both makes the function less flexible and creates the possibility of confusing bugs if the function changes the caller's state in unexpected ways.

Instead, take the value as an argument, and `return` the new value:

```
def count_input(numbers_of_letters, var):
    if numbers_of_letters == 0:
        return 13
    else:
        return int(var)
```

Now instead of:

```
a = "42"
count_input_a(13)
# a == 42
count_input_a(0)
# a == 13
```

you can do:

```
a = "42"
a = count_input(13, a)
# a == 42
a = count_input(0, a)
# a == 13
```

but you can do it with any variable, not just `a`.